# delete current line in python with print

Tags: python, printing

I'm executing code in python and want to update my status by rewriting the current line on the output. Example:

```
import time

print("1 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("2 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("3 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("BBBB")
print("c")
```

Now the output of this Code is

```
BBBBa a
c
```

How can I alter my code to have the following output?

```
BBBB
c
```

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get your output when i tried

Comment: `\r` doesn't delete code; it just moves the cursor. Whether and how previously written text is *overwritten* depends on your terminal.

Comment: run your code in terminal first, then post the qustion

Comment: your console seems to work different than mine. Could you try your code on repl.it? This one gives the same output as my installed python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` only moves the cursor; it doesn't delete text *per se*, it only provides the opportunity to overwrite existing text.

Pretty much anything you try will be terminal-dependent, but *usually* you are using one that uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). One such sequence *can* be used to clear the current line.

```
import time

print("\x1b[K1 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("\x1b[K2 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("\x1b[K3 a a a", end="\r")
time.sleep(1) #placeholder for doing stuff
print("\x1b[KBBBB")
print("c")
```

`\x1b[K` clears from the current cursor position to the end of the current line.

Libraries like `ncurses` can be used for terminal-independent handling of the screen.